# perspective.js for transparent PNGs is stretching the image

Tags: javascript, canvas, png

I'm trying to use perspective.js (https://github.com/wanadev/perspective.js/) to rotate and skew logos and place them in mockups. However, it seems to only work with images with background – if I'm trying to apply it for something else, the image stretches and covers with terrible pixels (example below)

Is the problem in canvas or perspective.js? How can I put something like a logo inside?

The code I have now is available at: https://github.com/kafq/perspective-png

[image]

Comment: "Image with background" – you mean, images without transparency? But it seems that the resolution of the pasted-in image is just too low here.

Comment: The script works for images with no transparency, yes. However, I'm trying to make it work for logos, for example. I can manage the resolution, it's not a problem, but the problem is that the image gets stretched to the bottom. The original image is just a small fork with nothing at bottom

Comment: @usr2564301 updated the repo